# Find all User that are NOT in a specifv Role using: Roles.GetUsersInRole or different

Tags: c#, asp.net, roleprovider

I need **populate an array with a list of Users that ARE NOT PRESENT in a specific Role** and COUNT the result.

At the moment I use this code, but I am not able to get the Users outside "CMS-ADMINISTRATOR " role.

Any idea how to do it and better write the Count section?

```
       string[] usersInRole;
       usersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole("CMS-ADMINISTRATOR");
       int c = usersInRole.Count();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the number of users not in the role, you can subtract the number of users in the role from the total number of users:

```
int count = Membership.GetAllUsers.Count - Roles.GetUsersInRole("CMS-ADMINISTRATOR").Count();
```

Comment: Hi Andy, which method should I use to list the TOTAL number of users? thanks

Comment: GetAllUsers method does not have a "Count" Property, but I got the idea thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try,

```
            var usernames = Roles.GetUsersInRole("Administrator");
            var adminUsers = db.UserProfiles
                 .Where(x => !usernames.Contains(x.UserName)).ToList();
```

`adminusers.count`

you can also return it to the view

```
return View(adminUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about getting users outside the "CMS-ADMINISTRATOR" role, but at least you can write the original code better like this:

```
 int count = Roles.GetUsersInRole("CMS-ADMINISTRATOR").Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
var users=Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()
           .Count(t=>!Roles.IsUserInRole(t.UserName,"CMS-ADMINISTRATOR"));
```

Or use what Andy Mikula suggests which is simpler if you just need the count.

Comment: be careful how long it will take: 1 user: 60ms; 10 users: 600ms; 100 users 6s: 1000 users: 1min

Comment: Weird. It should work. Let me look at it when I arrive to work and I'll try to correct it.

Comment: Thanks for your time, here just for reference i wrote some code following Andy advices MembershipUserCollection users;
                users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
                int countAllUsers = users.Count;

                int countUsersInRole = Roles.GetUsersInRole("CMS-ADMINISTRATOR").Count();
                if (countAllUsers - countUsersInRole > 0)